# Did making Nagini a horcrux made it immortal?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, horcrux, immortality

So, Voldemort thought it was a good idea to make Nagini one of the horcruxes.

**Did making Nagini ( or any other living creature, generally speaking ) a horcrux also make it immortal ?**

Because snakes have a limited life-span, and his ambitions to live and rule forever would not seem very secure, if part of his soul lied in a mortal being.

Comment: Why can't corpse of snake be indestructible?

Comment: @SachinShekhar - I don't know why not, but then again, does the corpse not disintegrate ?

Comment: Coz microbes can't eat a horcrux... :)

Comment: @SachinShekhar - Oh yea, I bet V paid a lot of attention to biology :D